# Term for repeated exponentiation?

Tags: terminology, exponentiation

Is there a term (or operation) for repeated exponentiation?

I.e. Repeated addition is multiplication, repeated multiplication is exponentiation, repeated exponentiation is X?

Is there even such a term for such a "higher order" operation, seeing as we could potentially deal with this by increasing the exponent?

Comment: Search for **tetration**

Answer (score 1):

The word you are looking for is probably [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration)

at least if you are looking for something like $$\underbrace{a^{(a^{(\cdot^{\cdot^{a)\cdots)}}}}}_n$$